# Find a finite automata that recognizes $L=\{w\in\{0,1,2\}^*\mid\text{$w$ has one $1$ and odd number of $0$}\}$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

> Find a finite automata that recognizes $$L=\{w\in\{0,1,2\}^*\mid\text{$w$ has only one $1$ and odd number of $0$'s}\}.$$

---

I don't think it is possible to construct such automata, but I am not able to prove it.

I have considered this question: [Find automata for $S\to01X\mid0S,\;X\to2X\mid1Y,\;Y\to2Y2\mid0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459158/find-automata-for-s-to01x-mid0s-x-to2x-mid1y-y-to2y2-mid0) but I am not able to split the language into $L_i$ sublanguages.

Is $L$ regular or not?

Comment: Regular. Your automamta needs to "remember" two things: whether it already saw 1 and whether the number of zeros he saw is even or odd.

Comment: @AmitKeinan thanks!! But if it is regular, then there exists a **regex** that generates the language. What would that regex be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, languages that are not regular require remembering an arbitrarily large amount of information. This language is not an example of this, as all you need to know is the current parity of the number of $0$s, and whether you have seen at least 1 and at most 1 $1$.

So, here's a DFA that reads the language:

$$Q=\{0,1,2\}\times\{0,1\}$$

$$\delta((a,b),c)=\begin{cases}(a,b)&c=2\\(\min(a+1,2),b)&c=1\\(a,1-b)&c=0\end{cases}$$
$$q_0=(0,0)$$$$F=\{(1,1)\}$$

The corresponding regex is $$2^*(0(2^*02^*0)^*2^*1(00)^*+2^*(02^*02^*)^*12^*0(2^*02^*0)^*2^*)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I think you write the automata in a hard way. Could you write it using the diagram, please?

Comment: @manooooh ... There are only $6$ states, if you are so inclined, you can draw it yourself.

Comment: I will try to draw it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the regex is correct since there is no word containing $\epsilon,2,22,222,\ldots=2^*$.

Comment: @manooooh Those aren't words in the language...

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the previous message since I am thinking your expression of $\delta$ and I realized it is right now (I have not finished yet). But the words $201$ and $01200$ are just examples of words that *are* in $L$, since both have only one $1$ and an odd quantity of $0$'s. Where is my mistake? Please help

Comment: And the regex accepts them. Honestly, it seems you are a bit lazy and not willing to do the basic job of understanding this answer.

Comment: Is this correct?: $$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
\delta((0,0),0)=(0,0)&\delta((0,0),1)=(1,0)&\delta((0,0),2)=(0,0)\\
\delta((0,1),0)=(0,1)&\delta((0,1),1)=(1,1)&\delta((0,1),2)=(0,1)\\
\delta((1,0),0)=(1,0)&\delta((1,0),1)=(2,0)&\delta((1,0),2)=(1,0)\\
\delta((1,1),0)=(1,1)&\delta((1,1),1)=(2,1)&\delta((1,1),2)=(1,1)\\
\delta((2,0),0)=(2,0)&\delta((2,0),1)=(2,0)&\delta((2,0),2)=(2,0)\\
\delta((2,1),0)=(2,1)&\delta((2,1),1)=(2,1)&\delta((2,1),2)=(2,1)\\
\end{array}$$ I will call $A=(0,0),B=(0,1),C=(1,0),D=(1,1),E=(2,0),F=(2,1)$, thus $q_0=A$ and $F_{\text{state}}=D$.

Comment: No, that's not correct. There are quite a few errors with that. One example: $\delta((1,1),0)=(1,0)$.

Comment: I think It was correct taking your previous edit, now you've changed $c\oplus b$ with $1\oplus b$. Now?: $$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
\delta((0,0),0)=(0,1)&\delta((0,0),1)=(1,0)&\delta((0,0),2)=(0,0)\\
\delta((0,1),0)=(0,0)&\delta((0,1),1)=(1,1)&\delta((0,1),2)=(0,1)\\
\delta((1,0),0)=(1,1)&\delta((1,0),1)=(2,0)&\delta((1,0),2)=(1,0)\\
\delta((1,1),0)=(1,0)&\delta((1,1),1)=(2,1)&\delta((1,1),2)=(1,1)\\
\delta((2,0),0)=(2,1)&\delta((2,0),1)=(2,0)&\delta((2,0),2)=(2,0)\\
\delta((2,1),0)=(2,0)&\delta((2,1),1)=(2,1)&\delta((2,1),2)=(2,1)\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I have made the automata and it looks very nice. Thank you again. Can you detail how you get the expression of $\delta$?

Comment: I just used Myhill-Nerode

Answer (score 1):

A 4-state automaton suffices:

$\hskip 100pt$[image]

Comment: Indeed, Myhill-Nerode suggests this is minimal. Regardless, I chose a $6$-state DFA as it was easier to describe.

Comment: @don-thousand This 4-state automaton is also very easy to describe: it is the product of a 2-state automaton recognising $\{u \mid |u|_0 \text{ is odd}\}$ and of a 2-state automaton recognising $(0,2)^*1(0,2)^*$